# SQL Query that returns all records whose values are contained in an array. Data Retrieval with Specific Conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to return all cities whose all postal codes are contained in an array of certain postal codes.

On the backend I have an array containing postal codes. The array looks as follows:
[41200, 41201, 41202, 42500, 42501, 42504, 42505, 42506].

Using sql query, I retrieve all available cities from the database along with all postal codes assigned to them. Example:

| City | Postcodes |
| --- | --- |
| New York | 10001, 10002, 10003, 10004, ... |

I want to add a certain condition to this query that will make the query return all cities whose all postal codes are included in this array.

Easy example:
Table: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
SQL query result:

| City | Postcodes |
| --- | --- |
| City 1 | 1, 2, 7 |
| City 2 | 1, 4 |
| City 3 | 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 |
| City 4 | 1, 3, 2, 8 |

After adding the condition, the query should return city 2 and city 3 BECAUSE table includes all of city 2 / city 3 postcodes but it does not include all the postcodes from city 1 and 4. Thank you.

That's my query:

```
SELECT gmina, kody
FROM (
    SELECT gmina, STRING_AGG(DISTINCT kod, ', ') AS kody
    FROM ser_strumieniowanie_kody ser
    LEFT JOIN hog_miasta hog ON ser.st_kod = hog.kod
    WHERE ser.pm = ser.av
    GROUP BY gmina
) AS subquery where ...
```

Comment: mysql or pstgres?

Comment: @nbk 
PostgreSQL

Comment: i don't understand your question

Comment: @nbk I have added a light additional explanation in the example at the very bottom.

Comment: so you have an array of numbers and try to find all city that have exclisuvly o9nly that numbers?

Comment: Do yourself a big favor and change your datamodel: Don't use arrays, use a 3NF datamodel. That will fix the root cause of many problems to come.

Comment: I want to return all records whose all comma-separated values are contained in an array. For a simple example:
Array: [1, 2, 3]
Records:
City 1 - [1, 2, 3]
City 2 - [1, 5, 8]
City 3 - [1, 3, 2]
Query will return city one and city 3 because all values are included in the table.

Comment: Sounds like the [`@>` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html), as long as you `array_agg()` into a proper array instead of a string looking like one.

Answer (score 0):

That needs a lot of conversions to have on bioth side arays

athen you can use <@ as array operator see
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html

```
select version();CREATE TABLE tab_city (
  "City" VARCHAR(6),
  "Postcodes" VARCHAR(16)
);

INSERT INTO tab_city
  ("City", "Postcodes")
VALUES
  ('City 1', '1, 2, 7'),
  ('City 2', '1, 4'),
  ('City 3', '1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6'),
  ('City 4', '1, 3, 2, 8');
```

```
SELECT "City"
FROM tab_city WHERE regexp_split_to_array("Postcodes", ',')::int[] <@ ARRAY[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

| City |
| --- |
| City 2 |
| City 3 |

> ```
> SELECT 2
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/n4QAvMYA)

Comment: Why store a string and split it, if you can store an array?

Comment: he doesn't explain what he needs the sting for, i guess for his application, but basically it doesn't matter

Answer (score 0):

Based on the query you added, I'm assuming you *are* dealing with a normalised structure and you only presented the values in an aggregated form to illustrate their intermediate state in your array-oriented approach.

If I'm guessing your columns right, you can swap out `string_agg()` for an [`array_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#id-1.5.8.27.5.2.4.2.1.1.1) to get access to array containment [operator `@>`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html) and its commutator `<@` and specify your condition in the [`HAVING`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-HAVING) clause. [Demo at db<>fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/x1aE-kgS)

```sql
SELECT gmina
FROM hog_miasta hog
GROUP BY gmina
HAVING ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT kod) 
    <@ (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT st_kod) 
        FROM ser_strumieniowanie_kody ser
        WHERE ser.pm = ser.av);
```

| gmina |
| --- |
| City 2 |
| City 3 |

In a `left join`, rows in the left table without a match in the right table get a *`null`* in all right table's columns. You could use that to only keep those cities where every code had a match:

```sql
SELECT gmina
FROM hog_miasta hog
LEFT JOIN ser_strumieniowanie_kody ser
       ON ser.st_kod = hog.kod
      AND ser.pm = ser.av
GROUP BY gmina
HAVING EVERY(ser.st_kod IS NOT NULL);
```

That's demonstrably faster, especially when supported by [covering indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-index-only-scans.html):

```sql
create index on hog_miasta (kod)
  include(gmina)
  with(fillfactor=100);

create index on ser_strumieniowanie_kody(st_kod)
  with(fillfactor=100)
  where pm=av;
```

At the end of [the demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/x1aE-kgS), there's a test on 200k records from 10k cities with up to 40 out of 300 codes.